# Unable to expand a browser tree with Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi I am trying to expand a '+' button in tree in a web page using Selenium.

I am using the below steps with selenium for expanding the tree.

```
  1.Select frame main
  2.select frame nav
  3.click on image with xpath       
    //img[contains(@src,'mypath/plus.gif')]
```

Code seems to be perfect as selenium is not throwing any exception,but it's not performing the click operation.Can anyone give leads on why it's not performing click operation?

Source code is there in the below link -

https://jsfiddle.net/sonashetty/uf6w62qx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issues by firing onmousedown event after activating the  '+' image